# Creating a "flashlight" effect on a specific container without JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a game for a project and wanted to add a flashlight effect on top of the game.

Looking for something similar to this, just to a specific container on my webpage: https://codemyui.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Flashlight-Mouse-Pointer.gif

I've tried to do it their way, but I cannot get it to work. It doesn't apply correctly to the container I want it to and the flashlight does not work.  I'm not allowed to use JQuery or any imports for this projecet, just HTML, CSS and JS. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code that applies:

```js
//game flashlight
function update(e) {
  var x = e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX
  var y = e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY

  let gameBox = document.getElementById('gameBox');
  gameBox.documentElement.style.setProperty('--cursorX', x + 'px')
  gameBox.documentElement.style.setProperty('--cursorY', y + 'px')
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', update)
document.addEventListener('touchmove', update)
```

```css
#gameContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1100px;
  float: right;
}

#gameContent {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;
  width: 1050px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #FFE29C;
  border-color: #E1AA72;
  border-width: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#gameBox {
  position: relative;
  height: 768px;
  width: 768px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #EABF7D;
  border-color: #E1AA72;
  border-width: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 12% 0 12%;
  line-height: 1em;
}


/* Flashlight Overlay */

#gameContent {
  cursor: none;
  --cursorX: 50vw;
  --cursorY: 50vh;
}

#gameBox:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: radial-gradient( circle 10vmax at var(--cursorX) var(--cursorY), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 80%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .95) 100%)
}
```

```html
<div id="gameContainer">
  <div id="gameContent">
    <div id="gameBox">
      <img id="mapFit" src="images/Temple_Escape.jpg" alt="main map">
      <img id="chest" src="images/chest.png" alt="main map" onclick="chestClick()">
      <img id="chestOpened" src="images/chestopened.png" alt="main map" onclick="chestClick()">
      <img id="gold1" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold1Click()">
      <img id="gold2" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold2Click()">
      <img id="gold3" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold3Click()">
      <img id="gold4" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold4Click()">
      <img id="gold5" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold5Click()">
      <img id="gold6" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold6Click()">
      <img id="podium" src="images/podium.png" alt="main map" onclick="podiumClick()">
      <img id="rope" src="images/rope.png" alt="main map" onclick="ropeClick()">
      <img id="skeleton" src="images/skeleton.png" alt="main map" onclick="skeletonClick()">
      <img id="brokenPickaxe" src="images/brokenpickaxe.png" alt="main map" onclick="pickaxeClick()">
      <img id="stoneSlab1" src="images/stoneslab.png" alt="main map" onclick="slab1Click()">
      <img id="stoneSlab2" src="images/stoneslab.png" alt="main map" onclick="slab2Click()">
      <img id="tile1" src="images/tile1.png" alt="main map" onclick="floorStoneClick()">
      <img id="door1" src="images/door1.png" alt="main map" onclick="exitDoorClick()">
      <img id="redOrb" src="images/redorb.png" alt="main map" onclick="">
      <img id="blueOrb" src="images/blueorb.png" alt="main map" onclick="">
      <img id="greenOrb" src="images/greenorb.png" alt="main map" onclick="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is what the website looks like with that code applied.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8pd9.jpg

Comment: To start with (though I don't know if this is your whole problem or not), look in your browser's dev tools console. You should see an error there at gameBox.documentElement.style.setProperty('--cursorX', x + 'px') You have just defined gameBox as an element, the .documentElement should not be there. (and likewise for the following line). Replace with gameBox.style.setProperty('--cursorX', x + 'px'). The flashlight then moves with the mouse.

Comment: Perfect, this is the answer. Please convert it to one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where `documentElement` came from, but it definitely not belong there..

Without it it seems to be working:

```js
//game flashlight
let gameBox = document.getElementById('gameBox');
function update(e) {
  var x = e.clientX || e.touches && e.touches[0].clientX || 0;
  var y = e.clientY || e.touches && e.touches[0].clientY || 0;

  gameBox.style.setProperty('--cursorX', 'calc(' + x + 'px + 9vmax)');
  gameBox.style.setProperty('--cursorY', 'calc(' + y + 'px - 6vmax)');
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', update)
document.addEventListener('touchmove', update)
```

```css
#gameContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1100px;
  float: right;
}

#gameContent {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;
  width: 1050px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #FFE29C;
  border-color: #E1AA72;
  border-width: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#gameBox {
  position: relative;
  height: 768px;
  width: 768px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #EABF7D;
  border-color: #E1AA72;
  border-width: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 12% 0 12%;
  line-height: 1em;
}


/* Flashlight Overlay */

#gameContent {
  cursor: none;
  --cursorX: 50vw;
  --cursorY: 50vh;
}

#gameBox:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: radial-gradient( circle 10vmax at var(--cursorX) var(--cursorY), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 80%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .95) 100%)
}
```

```html
<div id="gameContainer">
  <div id="gameContent">
    <div id="gameBox">
      <img id="mapFit" src="images/Temple_Escape.jpg" alt="main map">
      <img id="chest" src="images/chest.png" alt="main map" onclick="chestClick()">
      <img id="chestOpened" src="images/chestopened.png" alt="main map" onclick="chestClick()">
      <img id="gold1" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold1Click()">
      <img id="gold2" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold2Click()">
      <img id="gold3" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold3Click()">
      <img id="gold4" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold4Click()">
      <img id="gold5" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold5Click()">
      <img id="gold6" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold6Click()">
      <img id="podium" src="images/podium.png" alt="main map" onclick="podiumClick()">
      <img id="rope" src="images/rope.png" alt="main map" onclick="ropeClick()">
      <img id="skeleton" src="images/skeleton.png" alt="main map" onclick="skeletonClick()">
      <img id="brokenPickaxe" src="images/brokenpickaxe.png" alt="main map" onclick="pickaxeClick()">
      <img id="stoneSlab1" src="images/stoneslab.png" alt="main map" onclick="slab1Click()">
      <img id="stoneSlab2" src="images/stoneslab.png" alt="main map" onclick="slab2Click()">
      <img id="tile1" src="images/tile1.png" alt="main map" onclick="floorStoneClick()">
      <img id="door1" src="images/door1.png" alt="main map" onclick="exitDoorClick()">
      <img id="redOrb" src="images/redorb.png" alt="main map" onclick="">
      <img id="blueOrb" src="images/blueorb.png" alt="main map" onclick="">
      <img id="greenOrb" src="images/greenorb.png" alt="main map" onclick="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've added `calc()` so the flash light would stay centered to cursor.